# Method is not changing outer variable C#

Tags: c#, variables, global

I want to change a outer variable (var1) inside a method to be able to use a getter to return it's value. But somehow var1 is only changed within the function and not global. How do I change the value of var1 inside of a method globally?

The code is really simple:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float var1 = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        var1 = 5;
        print(var1);      // output: 5
    }

    public float GetVar1() 
    {  
        print(var1);
        return var1;     // output: 0
    }
}
```

The update method is called by the gameengine unity itself and the getter is called in another class.

The class that calls the getter is here:

```
public class bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    public PlayerMovement playerdata;
    private float output;



    void Update()
    {
        output = playerdata.GetVar1();
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls these methods?

Comment: That's not a whole code. My guess from what I see is that you're calling "Update" and "GetVar1" on different instances of "PlayerMovement". Can you add code that calls those methods?

Comment: Works fine: `Update(); var v = GetVar1();` prints 5 and v == 5 as expected. Perhaps you tried `var v = GetVar1(); Update(); ` thus you got 0 and 5. ...

Comment: Sounds like you need either a static class or a singleton.

Comment: The caller isn't calling `Update` on the `PlayerMovement playerdata` instance though? Hence its value is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect `output` of a `bullet` instance to be 5, then you need to call `Update()` on the `playerdata`  instance first:

```cs
public class bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement playerdata;
    private float output;

    void Update()
    {
        playerdata.Update();
        output = playerdata.GetVar1();
    }
}
```

I also note that unless `bullet` is incomplete code, you're not creating an instance of the `PlayerMovement` class, so you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
I did not expect that I have to call the update function by the class bullet itself again because I thought that it is already continious called by unity and by that changing the value globally.

Comment: @Stefan The above is standard C# code. I'll admit I've never actually used Unity. It seems like it has some odd behaviour, probably using reflection to determine whether the subclass has an `Update` method, instead of inheritance. Anyway...I found this, if it helps: https://forum.unity.com/threads/update-function-is-not-getting-called.330735/